# Text element only showing in Firefox, not safari or chrome

Tags: css, firefox, text

me and my friend are making this site and in firefox this certain text area is showing fine, but in safari and chrome it doesnt, it just is completely hidden.

http://skincache.com/request_reply

We have no idea why.

Thank you

Comment: It is the text area next to the thumbnail images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should inspect your code with Chrome Dev Tool or Firebug, because I can see this:

```
#request_reply ul li {
  height: 0px;
}
```

Disabling it solves the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much, just need my mate to update it but should work for sure.